# Реализация таблицы как в VKApp iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Подскажите, никак не могу понять, как реализована таблица в сообщениях VKApp iOS
[image]

Comment: различные кастомные contentView, добавленные через cell.contentView.addSubview(myCustomContentView).

типа базовый класс: VKMediaContentView <->>VKPhotoContentView, VKMultiPhotoContentVIew, VKVideoContentView, VKLocationContentView и тд., соответственно все это дело анализируется (возможно на лету, возможно заранее, высота ячейки точно заранее вычисляется) и кладется на cell.contentView

Comment: спасибо, теперь понял, как делать

Comment: Посмотри VKsdk для ios
она в свободном доступе и там точно должна быть реализация этого)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что блоки с днями - это секции, синие закругленные бабблы (и время рядом) - это ячейки. Сами бабблы и их контент, очевидно сделаны вручную. А возможно и вся таблица полностью самописная)